# Battery not detected on Surface 3 2GB, Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: power-management, battery, acpi, surface

I got a Surface 3 for my computer science classes, and proceeded to install on both my PCs Ubuntu.
The problem is that on the Surface, Ubuntu refuses to detect the battery:

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply
ADP1
```

which is kinda annoying, since I have no way to know when the tablet is going to shutdown.

The kernel version i'm using is `4.11.0-041100rc7-generic`, if that might help (though I had this problem since the beginning, so I don't think that the problem is the kernel update).

I don't really know what to do, I'm not really into Linux, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/5zx9qx/surface_3_nonpro_with_1704/ kernel 4.10 works perfectly  Your problem might be hardware related though, and not about the OS. Same happens on Windows.

Comment: The battery is detected under Windows

Comment: Yeah, now. But reports are it does not get detected 100% of the time on 100% of the surfaces. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro3-surfgetstart/battery-not-detected-surface-pro-3/d5666e2f-2e40-41ae-8fb2-d84a5154ef10 for a windows related troubleshooter.